# How to debug with npm test

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I am using VS Code. When I try to run the test in debug mode, it says describe is not a function. Thus, only way I am able to run the test is through npm Note.

Note: I am using mocha and chai.

```
var { describe,it, before, after } = require('mocha');
var assert = require('chai').assert;
var AuthAPI = require('../api/controllers/API.js');
     describe('getItem tests', function() {
    it('getItem ', function(done) {
      var API = new AuthAPI(clientId, PASS, List);

      api_jwt = API.getItem();
      assert.isNotEmpty(api_jwt);
    });
    )}
```

Comment: can you show us the code?

Comment: I have added the code below

Comment: Add the code to the question (use Edit), you cannot put it in the answer

Comment: I I have installed mocha globally and have the below require but when I run mocha it says describe is not a function :                                                      const { describe,it, before, after } = require('mocha');

Comment: @MANOJ I think this is expected, take a look at this opened discussion about new features in mocha https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/1969. I think you may want to use one of the solutions from my answer.

Answer (score 12):

I think you just need another launch configuration for your mocha tests.

Go to Debug section in your Visual Studio Code.

Click the select control, then select "Add Configuration..." (or just click the gear icon and then click the "Add Configuration..." button);

You should be able to select "Node.js: Mocha Tests" there, it would generate a launch config like that:

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Mocha Tests",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
    "args": [
        "-u",
        "tdd",
        "--timeout",
        "999999",
        "--colors",
        "${workspaceFolder}/test"
    ],
    "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
},
```

## !Note: starting from mocha 6 it requires a proper selection of the interface (https://mochajs.org/#interfaces), change tdd to bdd if you want to use `describe` functions.

Make sure your mocha tests are in `./test` folder and you have installed mocha locally or customise the launcher config.

Let's say you have a test `./test/it_should_work.js` (note, it does not have any require, since mocha binary knows that functions by itself)

```
describe('test', () => {
  it('should work', () => {
  });
})
```

Launch a newly created "Mocha Test" configuration, it should return a successful result.

```
test
    ✓ should work
  1 passing (9ms)
```

---

But if you really need to programmatically launch mocha tests, check out this official wiki page https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Using-mocha-programmatically.

Comment: @Nick thank you for your comment, please see the !Note section of the solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "Click the select control"? (Neither pressing Debug/Add Configuration.. or the Gear seems to do anything.) Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to specify if you use `tdd` or `bdd`. Mocha will figure that out. You only get into trouble if you force a specific style.

See example configuration in:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/debugging-mocha-tests